# HTML not parsing in Android

Tags: android, webkit

I know there is an issue with Android not parsing certain HTML elements, but it was my understanding that `strong` and `em` were parsed in Android 2.1 onwards. But on testing it on Android 2.2, the tags are not parsing. Is there a confirmed list of tags that are supported?

Source: http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

Comment: Is there a snippet of HTML that doesn't parse correctly that you can give as an example?

Comment: Text in `em` or `strong` isn't parsing when pulled from JSON. Also issues with how paragraphs are being formatted with \r\n appearing.

Comment: It sounds like there is more going on than what your original question describes. I'm guessing you are trying to have a server pass some markup via JSON data, then have the client render it - which I don't think is good practice. I would limit the JSON data to just that: data, not markup. Then let the client worry about how to render the data. That doesn't really answer your question so much as make it moot, but I think it would be the better way to go. (I may still not be understanding everything you're trying to do here.)

Comment: String data = 

`"rates":"<strong>High Season - July & August<\/strong>\r\n€40.00 Per Person Sharing, Per Night\r\n€55.00 Single\r\n\r\n<strong>Low Season - April, May, June, September & October<\/strong>\r\n€35.00 Per Person Sharing, Per Night\r\n€45.00 Single\r\n\r\n<strong>Superior rooms with private balconies overlooking Tramore Bay<\/strong>\r\n\r\n<em>25% discount for children under 12 years<\/em>"`

I want to render this data in Android TextView. For this I am using Html.fromHtml(data)
But it is not displaying parsing `<strong>` html tag.

Comment: The Android API documentation says that they're using [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) to parse HTML. The answers you seek may lie in the source code for that. To reiterate what I said before, I wouldn't be passing marked-up text via JSON anyway, because that muddles the lines between Model, View, and Controller.